# How do I connect to a Postgresql set up on docker, running on local host, with dbeaver?

Tags: postgresql, docker, localhost, dbeaver

I am running a postgresql database on docker, hosting it on my local machine. When I try and connect to it using DBeaver though, I am given the error:

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused.
Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
Connection refused: connect
```

Here are the commands I ran in Docker to create my PostgreSQL image:

```
rrowe@LAPTOP-AFM43BOB MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker run --name RiohRoweDB -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Charlie -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
55c78d059fdb2b19bfdd24f579eaf26ef5b00c77ead564ee7d128fd06996789d

rrowe@LAPTOP-AFM43BOB MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker exec -it RiohRoweDB bash
root@55c78d059fdb:/# psql -U postgres
psql (12.0 (Debian 12.0-2.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE postgresqlDB
postgres-# \q
root@55c78d059fdb:/# exit
exit

rrowe@LAPTOP-AFM43BOB MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
55c78d059fdb        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   RiohRoweDB
```

On the DBeaver side, I add a connection with the following parameters:

```
Host:localhost
Port:5432
Database:postgresqlDB
User:postgres
Password:Charlie
```

When I test the connection ("Test Connection" button in Connection Settings)

I get the following error:

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused.
Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
Connection refused: connect
```

I was following this tutorial that did not use DBeaver: https://medium.com/better-programming/connect-from-local-machine-to-postgresql-docker-container-f785f00461a7

Comment: I am not able to view the link. Please post the docker-compose or Dockerfile

Comment: It's not immediately clear how you arrived at this condition.  Your code snippets indicate that you may have been tinkering around with things, and then ended up in the state you're in.  What is your current `listen_addresses` setting?  Maybe share `SHOW listen_addresses` output?

Comment: If you're using Docker Toolbox, programs on the host need to use the IP address from `docker-machine ip`, usually 192.168.99.100, to reach container processes; `localhost` won't work.

Comment: #pissall     -         The tutorial did not come with a Dockerfile, nor did I create one. I did a search, but could not find one in my project directory. Is there a specific place I should look for this file?

#richyen. I tried using the "SHOW listen_addresses" command in docker (docker: 'SHOW' is not a docker command) and in the bash given for the postgresql within the container. (bash: SHOW: command not found.) Am I calling this in the right environment?

Comment: #DavidMaze    Thank you. That solved my problem. For some reason, the CREATE DATABASE command I am using is not creating a database, But I should be able to figure that out from here.

Answer (score 9):

If you got here from the official [Postgres Docker page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres?tab=description), don't forget to add the port-forwarding flag `-p 5432:5432` to your initialization command like Rioh did above:

```
docker run --name RiohRoweDB -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Charlie -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

Also consider studying this how-to on Medium:

https://medium.com/@wkrzywiec/database-in-a-docker-container-how-to-start-and-whats-it-about-5e3ceea77e50

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Docker Toolbox, programs on the host need to use the IP address from docker-machine ip, usually 192.168.99.100, to reach container processes; localhost won't work. – David Maze

Comment: Thanks for this. This actually solved my problem. To find your WSL IP, Open Powershell then run wsl hostname -I.